# Configuring ember-data for embedded app

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Trying to use Ember and Ember-Data for an Ember app which is embedded in an existing site at URL:

`(my-site)/patients`

I have a REST/JSON endpoint at:

`(my-site)/smart/patients`

which returns json as directed by the Ember guide:

`{"patients":[{"id":1,"user_id":6,....] }`

My js looks like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
        rootElement: '#patient-data',
        LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
        LOG_TRANSITIONS_INTERNAL: true,
        LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
    });

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('patients');
});

App.PatientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
            return this.store.find('patient');
            }
    });

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    url: 'http://(my-site)/smart'
});

App.Patient = DS.Model.extend({
    userId: DS.attr('number'),
    etc...
});

App.PatientView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
         do stuff...
        });
    }
});
```

I am able to get this working by using (with root element `[patients]` removed from JSON response):

```
    App.PatientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
        model: function() {
            return Ember.$.getJSON('http:(my-site)/smart/patients');
            }
    });
```

But, I can't get the `RESTAdapter` to do anything in the `PatientsRoute`...

I feel like I've tried every permutation of rootURL (`App.Router`), url (`DS.Store`), etc and can't get this to function...what am I missing?

Comment: in your adapter, try to set an attribute `namespace: 'smart'`

Comment: ok I changed the code to: DS.RESTAdapter.extend({namespace: 'smart'}); and App.Store = DS.Store.extend({adapter: DS.RESTAdapter})...no dice, ember inspector isn't showing any view tree, getting console error "Error while processing route: patients undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: When you remove the App.Store part and set the namespace to 'smart', what is the URL Ember is calling for your data?

Comment: No call/request is being made as far as I can tell...

Comment: OK, stupid alert: I was using Bower to install Ember/Ember-Data, and was getting pre-1.0 Ember Data.  After updating to Ember: 1.11.0 and Ember-Data: 1.0.0-beta.16 the RESTAdapter is making requests...many thanks to all who responded!